# Route URI to a specific folder in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

**Introduction :**

I have this path in my CakePHP : app/webroot/storage/5/C/_demo/omar.txt , this one will be redirected to `http://localhost/storage/5/C/_demo/omar.txt`

**My problem :**

I want this path `http://localhost/storage/5/C/_demo/omar.txt` to be something like this `http://localhost/storage/uehKDj44/C/_demo/omar.txt` , where **uehKDj44** is number **5** , the reason why I'm doing like that is I don't want anyone to change number 5 to any number so they can't access otherwise they login first , let's say if 5 belongs to a user will be open , but if not won't be open , is there any better way to secure it better than that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing restricted data as plain files inside of the htdocs folder (or `webroot` for CakePHP), where they can be requested without further authorization is always a risky business and should be avoided.

I cannot determine what kind of data you store in the .txt file, but I assume it is not fetched from the database and then saved. My understanding is that the link to the file is displayed to a logged in (authorized) user.

Proposal of a more secure solution:

1. Move the files outside of the `webroot` folder and create a constant with the absolute path to that folder (`USERDATA_PATH`). Remember to set read permission for web server user (`www-data` for Apache)
2. Create a model, e.g. `UserData` with an underlying database table storing a relation between a user and a magic hash (e.g. 1 => 'uehKDj44', 2 => 'ds83skf' etc.). You can also store file names to make it a bit less complicated.
3. Create a controller `UserDataController` with an action `serveFile` which will take the secret key as a parameter, match it with the file and output the file to the user.

> ```
> public function serveFile($hash= null) {
>
>   try
>   {
>     $data = $this->UserData->findByHash($hash);
>     if (!$data) {
>       throw new Exception('No match found');  
>     }
>
>     // Load the data from file 
>     $this->set('output', file_get_contents(USERDATA_PATH.DS.$data['UserData']['filename']));                   
>   }
>   catch (Exception $ex) 
>   {
>     // No match found - display error message / log
>   } 
> }
> ```

Then in view:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain'); 
echo $output;
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Is this solution applicable to any type of files not necessary to be *txt (I might have like a whole website there like *html , *css , *php) ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please be more specific.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to build a simple web IDE (same idea as cloud9 or kodigen but in simple idea) , I want to give user privileges to create projects , edit them and view them , like a desktop IDE ,,, this IDE is basically meant only for HTML , CSS < JS , something like Cloud9 or Kodigen .. Also those HTML files will have dependencies to any JS or CSS ,,,

Comment: My solution will work with any type of files, it is basically a pattern for a simple file dispatcher. The UserData (or UserFiles) model could store relation between userId and file and controller - upon authorization - serve requested file only if it belongs to the given user. Nonetheless, I cannot see any reason to store the files in the webroot folder.

Comment: OK , I have got what you mean , I have tested your solution , is working with all type of files perfectly , I guess before I didn't know the way to use "file_get_contents" ,, Thanks again for help ..